# Visual Studio VB application Installation Error: "The system cannot find the file specified. "

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

I have a VB application that won't install on a particular laptop. When I click setup.exe nothing happens and no error message appears. When I try it on other machines, it installs correctly.

After repeatedly clicking setup.exe, this popped up:

```
The following properties have been set: 
Property: [AdminUser] = true {boolean} 
Property: [InstallMode] = HomeSite {string} 
Property: [ProcessorArchitecture] = AMD64 {string} 
Property: [VersionNT] = 6.1.1 {version} 
Running checks for package 'Windows Installer 3.1', phase BuildList 
The following properties have been set for package 'Windows Installer 3.1': 
Running checks for command 'WindowsInstaller3_1\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe' 
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'VersionMsi' and value '3.1': true 
Result of checks for command 'WindowsInstaller3_1\WindowsInstaller-KB893803-v2-x86.exe' is 'Bypass' 
'Windows Installer 3.1' RunCheck result: No Install Needed 
Running checks for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)', phase BuildList 
Reading value 'Version' of registry key 'HKLM\Software\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Client' 
Read string value '4.5.50938' 
Setting value '4.5.50938 {string}' for property 'DotNet40Client_TargetVersion' 
The following properties have been set for package 'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)': 
Property: [DotNet40Client_TargetVersion] = 4.5.50938 {string} 
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe' 
Result of running operator 'ValueEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': true 
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_x86_x64.exe' is 'Bypass' 
Running checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe' 
Result of running operator 'ValueNotEqualTo' on property 'InstallMode' and value 'HomeSite': false 
Result of running operator 'VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo' on property 'DotNet40Client_TargetVersion' and value '4.0.30129': true 
Result of checks for command 'DotNetFX40Client\dotNetFx40_Client_setup.exe' is 'Bypass' 
'Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile (x86 and x64)' RunCheck result: No Install Needed 
Launching Application. 
Application appears to be an application manifest 
Launching application manifest via dfshim 
LaunchApplication failed with HRESULT '-2147023170' 
Running command 'C:\Users\s.maranan\Desktop\Infra_System_App.application' with arguments '' 
ShellExecuteEx failed with error code 2 
Error: The following error occurred attempting to install 'C:\Users\s.maranan\Desktop\Infra_System_App.application': 
"The system cannot find the file specified. "
```

The laptop has .NET Framework V4 installed but error persists.
Any help would be appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting all instances of Visual Studio from the computer then redownloading the installer from a verified source. If you can't get it through Microsoft directly and are a student, you might be able to get a copy of Ultimate 2014 through your school.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out. But the other machines don't have Visual studio installed and yet they still work.

Answer (score 0):

Is your setup.exe made for AMD64 ? May try to compile it for this processor architecture.